# Entity Framework Code First, DTO and n-tier scenario (WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, ef-code-first, n-tier-architecture

I've read several articles about bunch of EF and DTO, and I need some clarification about using EF Code First and DTO in n-tier scenario with WCF.

Let's look a these classes:

```
public class Order
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; private set; }  
}

public class OrderDetail
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

When user want to edit existing order, my client application (WPF MVVM app) requests some DTO, which then being converted to `Order` instance. Then, user makes some changes in order through UI - e.g., changes `ShipDate`, removes two positions, modifies one, and adds one.

Now I want to deliver changes to the server. As far as I understand DTO concept, I need to construct some DTO type, containing info about changes has been made:

```
[DataContract]
public class UpdateOrderDTO
{
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public Collection<OrderDetail> NewDetails { get; private set; }
  [DataMember]
  public Collection<OrderDetail> ModifiedDetails { get; private set; }
  [DataMember]
  public Collection<OrderDetail> DeletedDetails { get; private set; }
}
```

But **when**, and where should I to create this DTO? I mean, I can't create it on submitting changes - there's no change tracking information in `Order` class.

Looks like, this object have to be created together with `Order` after it was requested for edition by user. This allows to track changes... Am I wrong?

Please note, that the question isn't about STEs. For some reasons, I don't want/can't use them in current project.

Thanks a lot for sharing your experience.

Comment: If there is no change tracking information in the `Order` class you must track changes elsewhere - in some custom client class (for example by listening on events from your application logic) and pass those changes to server when needed. Check WCF data services - they can simplify this because they have client context for change tracking.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: the question is "where should I track changes"? Can DTO be such class? Or, maybe, it should be some separate class? What is the best practice? (WCF Data Services in not an option, I would like to use DTOs between service and clients).

Comment: SOA is stateless, you need to define the state protocol and pass the state back and forth as a part of your DTO.

Comment: @sza: I know that SOA is stateless. To build DTO, I need change tracking information. So, I need change tracker at client somewhere. Where? Should I make separate layer for change tracking purposes only? Or should I place change tracking in client's domain classes? If so, then what is the difference between this implementation and STE (from the point of client complexity)? The samples everywhere are toy samples, they're not related to real situations.

Comment: @Dennis Generally, the CRUD is determined by the HTTP methods like PUT/GET/POST/DELETE, you need to just make call to your WCF service per action triggered in your client side. If you have to save objects with foreign key relationship, you need to create the DTO on server side, and in your client side, wrap the data in DTO and send it back to WCF.